iPad's Magic Keyboard Not Responding After Setting Up CodeSpaces
I am trying to set up GitHub codespaces on my new iPad Pro so I can code on it at Uni.
I started by going to the Visual Studio Code (online) website and connected to my Uni Github Account. To run any (python code) I needed to set up the codespaces so I created one.
When I am on Safari everything seems to be working. But when I created a shortcut to the codespaces - meaning "Add to Homepage" from Safari, and tried to access it something weird happened.
Every time I connect, the Touch works, but my keyboard does not respond; I can't write any code, log in to my account, or do anything.
I would like to know if someone has encountered the same problem or has a solution to this problem!
